# Best way to lookup numbers in multiples of 3's C#

Tags: c#, math

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to overwrite services.

I have 3 lists. List1, List2 and List3. I want all my lists to take care of any numbers in multiples of 3's.

A count will come in. If the number is 1 go to List 1. If the number is 4, go to List1. If the number is 9 go to List 3.

For example:

```
List1 will deal with 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16 etc
List2 will deal with 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17 etc
List3 will deal with 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18 etc
```

I hope that makes sense.

Rather than setting up tables or cases, I'd prefer a simple mathematical approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [Modulus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx) function. It returns remainder from division operation.

```
int number = 4;
int result = number % 3;
```

here result will be 1 which was required and so on.

This is best way to lookup numbers in multiples of 3's C#

Answer (score 2):

You need to use modular maths. To do this you just need something like:

```
int listNumber = input % 3;
```

This will output 0, 1 or 2 for any positive integer. 0 will in this case represent list 3.

How you then use this will depend on how your Lists are stored, etc. but hopefully should be a simple exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
var listSelector = number % 3;
switch(listSelector)
{
case 0:
list3.add(number);
break;
case 1:
list1.add(number);
break;
case 2:
list2.add(number);
break;
}
```

0 would land into list3 as 0 % 3 == 0

Comment: With this method you are putting 1 into list 2 which wasn't what the OP was after. Other than the 0 to list 3 the others should go to the same numbered list.

Comment: Fixed 1 and 2 going in the wrong lists, however your statement that numbers other than 0-3 would go in the same list is wrong as since the modulo operation will sort them in their right list.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>         var lists = new[] {
>             new List<int>(),
>             new List<int>(),
>             new List<int>()
>         };
>
>         var listToDoStuffWith = lists[inputNumber % 3];
> ```

Comment: Although your answer may work, it will be good if add some explanation and background of your approach